# Rasterizing a Boolean vectorial file

Tags: qgis, rasterization, nodata

[image]When I try to rasterize a Boolean vector file in QGIS I just get the ones values, what can I do to get both values (0,1)? There is no "nodata" values in the file.

Comment: Presence/absence *has* to have an absence code (aka 0). Rasters are *inherently* continuous (mutually exclusive, exhaustively complete). Are you *sure* there isn't a NODATA code?

Comment: @Vince There is NODATA values, my question is how can I get cero values instead of NODATA?

Comment: Is it 1-bit? Maybe you could set the NODATA to be -1 or 2

Comment: I would perhaps set the output type into byte (8 bit) and set the nodata value into 255.

Comment: @user30184 Thank you so much your solution works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resulting file would contain 3 distinct raster values: 0, 1, and some third value for presenting the nodata.

I suggest creating the output as an 8 bit raster. It has place for 256 distinct values. Use 0 and 1 for the data and for example 255 for the nodata.

Comment: 4-bit would take half the storage (but would require a 15 NODATA)